# Most efficient way to clone a list into an existing list, minimizing memory reallocation?

Tags: c#, performance, list, memory-management, clone

I have a need to clone an existing list into another, existing list. As the environment demands very high performance, I need to eliminate unnecessary memory reallocation.

The most efficient algorithm I can think of is the following, which will increase the capacity of the destination list to match the source one as required, but will not decrease its own. (This is acceptable behavior for this project.)

```
    public static void CloneInto(this List<T> source, List<T> destination)
    {
        if (destination.Capacity < source.Capacity)
        {
            /* Increase capacity in destination */
            destination.Capacity = source.Capacity;
        }

        /* Direct copy of items within the limit of both counts */
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Count && i < destination.Count; i++)
        {
            destination[i] = source[i];
        }

        if (source.Count > destination.Count)
        {
            /* Append any extra items from source */
            for (var i = destination.Count; i < source.Count; i++ )
            {
                destination.Add(source[i]);
            }
        } 
        else if (source.Count < destination.Count)
        {
            /* Trim off any extra items from destination */
            while (destination.Count > source.Count)
            {
                destination.RemoveAt(destination.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

However this seems a lot of code, logic and loops.

Is there a more efficient way to clone a list into an existing list while avoiding unnecessary memory allocations?

Comment: Have you tested a.Concat(b) in your environment?

Comment: I'm not sure how .Concat() would fit into this? When source has greater items, I guess I could .Concat() the tail part as destination.Concat(source.Skip(destination.Count)) - is that what you mean?

Comment: This seems like a wrong design in the function signature. Are you sure that's mandatory? For example, setting `destination.Capacity` to a larger value than the current value causes a reallocation and copy of the list (With unwanted, immediately overwritten values). If the signature would return the destination list you could simply create a copy and return that if the capacity isn't large enough.

Comment: Did you measure/benchmark anything? How big are those Lists in general? This looks like an ill-advised optimization. Don't spent time on problems you don't have.

Comment: If raw performance is important, why not forego `List<T>` and use `T[]`? Zero-based, one-dimensional arrays (aka vectors) are directly supported by the runtime, while `List<T>` is a type built on top of that (and so is likely to have some overhead, however small).

Comment: Shouldn't we move this to [CodeReview Stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (destination.Capacity < source.Capacity)
{
    /* Increase capacity in destination */
    destination.Capacity = source.Capacity;
}
```

This is probably wrong... The `source.Capacity` could be bigger than necessary...

And you are "copying" the elements already contained in `destination` to a "new" `destination` "buffer". This copy is unnecessary because then the elements of `destination` are discarded

So you should at least:

```
if (destination.Capacity < source.Count)
{
    /* Increase capacity in destination */
    destination.Clear();
    destination.Capacity = source.Capacity;
}
```

In this way, if the `Capacity` is changed, no elements need to be copied (note that I'm using the `Capacity = Count`, because while this would economize memory in the short term, in the long term it could cause multiple allocations of memory). Note that I'm checking against the `source.Count`, but for the assignment of `Capacity` I'm using the same `source.Capacity`. This to minimize reallocations of `destination` if the method is called multiple times.

Small optimization:

```
if (destination.Capacity < source.Count)
{
    /* Increase capacity in destination */
    destination.Capacity = 0;
    destination.Capacity = source.Capacity;
}
```

This because `List.Clear()` uses `Array.Clear()`, so it really zeroes the internal elements, while `destination.Capacity = 0` is optimized to simply reassign the internal array to a `static _emptyArray`.

You could even try:

```
public static void CloneInto(this List<T> source, List<T> destination)
{
    destination.Capacity = 0; // or destination.Clear();
    destination.AddRange(source);
}
```

but by looking at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,79de3e39e69a4811), I think it is slower than necessary (because it first copies the elements to `T[] itemsToInsert = new T[count];`, so it does two copies of the elements...

Then:

```
while (destination.Count > source.Count)
{
    destination.RemoveAt(destination.Count - 1);
}
```

can be optimized to:

```
destination.RemoveRange(source.Count, destination.Count - source.Count);
```

Comment: I think you meant to compare `destination.Capacity < source.Count` and set `destination.Capacity = source.Count` in the middle code fragment.

Comment: @Amit I decided to **not** apply that part of the comment. I've added an explanation of why.

Comment: Whether setting capacity to count or capacity will be a factor in some future is a function of how this function is used. You might be right, and might just as well be wrong without profiling. That said, the if condition is a mistake regardless of anything, since if `destination.Capacity` is large enough to accommodate `source.Count` there is no reason to reallocate.

Comment: @Amit I see what you mean... Changed.

Comment: xanatos I agree with your critiques. in the case that source.Count > destination.Capacity then the most efficient method is probably just destination = source.ToList().

Answer (score 1):

Little test on perfomance :

```
public static List<T> CloneInto<T>(List<T> source, List<T> destination)
{
    if (destination.Capacity < source.Capacity)
    {
        /* Increase capacity in destination */
        destination.Capacity = source.Capacity;
    }

    /* Direct copy of items within the limit of both counts */
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Count && i < destination.Count; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }

    if (source.Count > destination.Count)
    {
        /* Append any extra items from source */
        for (var i = destination.Count; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            destination.Add(source[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (source.Count < destination.Count)
    {
        /* Trim off any extra items from destination */
        while (destination.Count > source.Count)
        {
            destination.RemoveAt(destination.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    return destination;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        list1.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());                
    }

    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

    s.Start();
    CloneInto(list1, list2);

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Your Method: " + s.Elapsed.Ticks);

    s.Reset();
    s.Start();

    list2 = list1.ToList();

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("ToList() Method: " + s.Elapsed.Ticks);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

result:

[image: Test]

But if it is all about memory only - your method is better than .ToList() and there isn't much you can do to improve performance even more. May be you can use parallel loops like parallel.for but not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
destination = source.ToList();
```

ToList() creates a copy of the list and everything which was in destination before, will immediately be ready for garbage collection after the assignment.

Comment: Read the question, he wantd to move collection to existing collection.

Comment: LInsoDeTeh, yes that achieves the purpose functionally, but causes extra GC work, and in the scenario that destination.Capacity >= source.Capacity, it will result in unnecessary memory allocations. Not optimal performance & memory usage.

Comment: I've read the question. It will exactly do that. After the code, destination will have exactly the same entries as source, the same result as your code has.

Comment: @BrendanHill - with moderate-sized Lists, the GC will have _less_ work this way.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh after that line of code, `destination` has a new reference, to a new object, and as soon as the function returns, that reference will be gone and garbage collected later. The variable used to pass the original reference (in the outside function call) would still have a reference to the original unmodified list. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Henk - in the case where destination.Capacity > source.Capacity, then in my algorithm, the GC has no work to do whatsoever. Calling .ToList() causes GC work to be required, along with extra memory allocated temporarily.